# Получение value из элемента select asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток, есть проблема, необходимо получить значение атрибута value из элемента select на странице.

```
<form name="test">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Тестовое поле</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("Test", null, new { @class = "inputfield", @ID = "test" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

И вот код контроллера

```
class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<ViewResult> Step2()
    {
        List<Tests> asd = null;
        var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://comp-name:808/")};
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Tests");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            asd = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Tests>>();
        ViewData["Test"] = new SelectList(asd.Where(a => a.Name != null), "Id", "Name");

        return View();
  }
```

Проблема в том, что не могу понять, как можно выдернуть значение "Id" из списка через средства htmlhelper, а не через средства javascript.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: куда вы его выдернуть хотите? Если не через js, то вам всего лишь нужно сделать submit формы

Comment: По сути необходимо сделать динамические списки (например: страна/города), но чтобы получить список стран, нужно получить id страны, который записан в атрибуте value у первого выпадающего списка

Comment: Это в любом случае js. Никуда не деться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если получить значение выбраного элемента выпадающего списка то можно так

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".form-control.modal-edit-form").change(function () {
            $.get(
                "Controller/Action",
                {
                    value: $(this).val(),
                },
                success
            );
            function success(data) {
///тут что нить сделать с ответом если это надо
            }
        });
    })
```